# Where does Docker for Mac store PersistentVolume data on the local filesystem when using a HostPath?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes PersistentVolume that mounts a directory using HostPath and it is cumbersome to boot up a Pod and exec onto it to view or change the data in that volume. Is it possible to locate the data in this volume on my local file system instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker stores these volumes in `/Users/username/.docker/Volumes/your-pv-name/pvc-SOME-UUID`.

You can actually find the exact location by inspecting the PersistentVolume directly:

```
$ kubectl get pv -o=jsonpath='{.spec.hostPath.path}' some-persistent-volume-claim
/Users/youruser/.docker/Volumes/your-pv-name/pvc-4eafca67-3e94-11e8-9f11-025000000001
```